# Android 10 GPS Pings in Background

Tags: android, android-gps, locationlistener, android-fusedlocation

With existing mobile tracking implementation we were getting logistic user's location (co-ordinates,speed etc.) using Android locationManager background service.

This implementation was working fine till Android OS 9(Pie). But with OS 10(Q) upgrade, android increased restrictions on background services & other stuff.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

In android 10, pings or location fix is received intermittently.

Tried using FusedLocationListner, but not receiving location updates (e.g. every 3 mins).

Please suggest if you have any alternative implementation or fix.

Comment: At which accuracy you're trying to get location in fused-location services ?

Comment: With Fine Accuracy

Comment: Did you find any solution ?